# Long running process / write stdout to files / split at X GB chunks

Tags: command-line, unix

I have a long running process and I expect the log files to run into multiple hundreds of GBs. The program is a pre-compiled binary - so I can't modify the logic in the code.

Is there a command like tool (like `tee`) to which I can redirect my output. This tool would then write the stdout of my long running process to disk and start writing a new file as soon as I hit a certain limit (say, 1GB).

Here's what I have in mind:

```
%> long-running.sh | responsible-logger --max-length 1G output%02d.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**logrotate** is the big shot of unix to split arbitrary amount of logs to chunks of given properties. A smaller but more standard tool is **split** which has a shorter learning curve: http://linux.die.net/man/1/split

Comment: I did not realize you can use `split` with piped input too - I think I'll stick to that!